# Error al consumir un web service en una aplicación de consola C#

Tags: c#, webservice, consola

Quiero consumir un servicio desde una aplicacion de consola.

Al proyecto donde se implementa el servicio le agregue la referencia al mismo y cuando ejecuto el programa me da este errror:

> "No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace referencia al contrato 'EL NOMBRE DEL SERVICIO' en la sección de configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no se encontró ningún elemento de extremo correspondiente a este contrato en el elemento de cliente."

```cs
string archivo = Factura.Obtener(facturas);

SW.GTICargaBatchSoapClient servicio = new SW.GTICargaBatchSoapClient();

string response = servicio.insertarFacturas(archivo, usser, pass);
```

El error aparece cuando quiero instanciar el objeto del tipo `SW.GTICargaBatchSoapClient`

Comment: Deberías poner algún código de ejemplo al menos sino como vamos a a guiarte

Comment: Ahi edite la consulta para que se vea donde llamo al web service y que es lo que deberia devolverme. Gracias!

Comment: Hola. Puedes mostrarnos el archivo web.config?